# How to save ID as string in DB with Code-First EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, model, ef-code-first

I have a model:

```
    public class Something
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name{ set; get; }
    }
```

Also I have this class:

```
    public class SomethingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Something>
    {
        public SomethingConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(t => t.Id).Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine and the `Id` generates automatically after inserting to DB and save changes (commit).

Now I want to add another column  `IdString` (`Id` as string instead of int), so I can use it for searching-by-Id manipulations (autocompletes and more). How can I add `IdString` column that will get the automatic Id as string and will be save automatically while inserting and saving? Is it possible?

Comment: What makes you think that you can't do searching, autocompletes etc. with an integer column?

Comment: I can't do Id.contains(queryString) because it's an int. I can do Id.toString().contains(queryString) but for that I must use ".ToList()" int the linq query, and I want to keep using "IQuariable" queries, not lists (for performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql Server you can define a computed column with an underlying formula.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Something Add IsString  AS cast(Id as nvarchar)
```

These columns can be mapped in you model like this.

```
public partial class Something
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string IdString { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

this.Property(p => p.IdString)
    .HasMaxLength(30)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

And then used in your query.

```
var data1 = db.Something.Where(p => p.IdString.Contains("123"));
```

Because of the DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed definition, EntityFramework will request the current Value of the column every time you update the row.

But if you only want a translatable version of ToString() for an integer value you could just use SqlFunctions.StringConvert instead.

```
var data = db.Something
                .Where(p => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)p.Id).Contains("12"));
```

**Update:**
Add computed column with a Migration.

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Something",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Something Add IsString  AS cast(Id as nvarchar)");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropTable("dbo.Something");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you DB Has to be generated somehow. Do you use Migrations?

Comment: Not yet. It's a new project. I can delete the DB and create a new one with a Seed function. Where do I write the first line?

Comment: In other words - I added "HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)", now how the DB knows to compute IdString from Id?

Comment: You can do this with a Migration. I updated the answer.

Comment: Just to make sure you understood. If you only want to do a string.contains on an integer column you dont need a second property. Just the sqlfunctions.stingconvert method

Comment: Thanks! I used "SqlFunctions.StringConvert" and it works great.